# How to sign an App for the App Store, including its framework's .plist?

Tags: cocoa, app-store, plist, sign, codesign

After so many days and tries, it's time to ask for help...

Xcode (6.4 or 7.1) signs my App, including the 2 frameworks that I use, since I check "code sign on copy" in the "copy files".
I "Submit to the App Store". I believe, all is good then I got the iTunes email:

*Unable to Sign - This package doesn't meet the current code signing requirements. Specifically, codesign generated the following error:
    com.raphael.photobooth.pkg/Payload/SLR Pro Picture Booth.app/Contents/Frameworks/EDSDK.framework/Versions/A: code object is not signed at all
    In subcomponent: com.raphael.photobooth.pkg/Payload/SLR Pro Picture Booth.app/Contents/Frameworks/EDSDK.framework/Versions/A/DeviceInfo.plist*

I've never been good with codesign, but I learnt and tried the "--deep" flag (nope), or I signed manually this .plist from the terminal, or I used Application Loader. Either way in the end I can see that it re-signs those 2 Frameworks, but not this .plist, so it fails.
(and those Frameworks are not mine so I can't sign them using their source)

Even though I read and researched, signing still seems blurry to me, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It is common and complex problem which was well described (and solved) in great articles by Craig Hockenberry:

- [Code Signing and Mavericks](http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/) (especially about why `--deep` is bad solution)
- [Code Signing in El Capitan](http://furbo.org/2015/07/23/code-signing-in-el-capitan/)
- [Mac App Store guide](http://furbo.org/2011/03/09/mac-app-store-guide/)

**TL;DR:** You should not use `--deep` flag. You should use additional build steps for signing.